# Azure B2C - Migrating users from SQL Database to B2C tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are looking for any template or process available to migrate users that exist within an existing SQL Database into B2C users for their tenant. We also would need to validate the user's passwords prior to creation of these migrated users.

Is there any type of script/process you can suggest for completing such a B2C Tenant migration task.

Answer (score 4):

The Azure AD B2C team have published guidance for migration of identities at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration.

If you don't have access to credentials in the current database (which I am hoping is true), then you might consider a "hybrid" migration, where:

1. During the migration period (e.g. a few days, weeks, or months) as users are signing themselves into or resetting passwords with the current identity provider, you create an Azure AD B2C identity for them with their current or new password.
2. At the end of the migration period, you create Azure AD B2C identities for all of the remaining users with a random password.

The key objective of this hybrid migration is to be friendly to users that are active during the migration period.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any type of script/process you can suggest for completing
>   such a B2C Tenant migration task.

Yes, you can use the Azure AD Graph API to achieve that. Also,we can migrate user accounts with hashed passwords to Azure AD B2C now.

See more details about a new guide to User migration to Azure AD B2C in [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration)

> We also would need to validate the user's passwords prior to creation
>   of these migrated users.

There is two flows in this migration. Whether you can access the users' passwords or not, you can both migrate them easily.

**Pre-migration:** This flow applies when you either **have clear access to a user's credentials (user name and password) or the credentials are encrypted**, but you can decrypt them. The pre-migration process involves reading the users from the old identity provider and creating new accounts in the Azure AD B2C directory.

**Pre-migration and password reset:** This flow applies **when a user's password is not accessible.** For example:
The password is stored in HASH format.
The password is stored in an identity provider that you can't access. Your old identity provider validates the user credential by calling a web service.

In both flows, you first run the pre-migration process, read the users from your old identity provider, and create new accounts in the Azure AD B2C directory. If you do not have the password, you create the account by using a password that's generated randomly. You then ask the user to change the password or, when the user signs in for the first time, Azure AD B2C asks the user to reset it.

Also, if you are unfamiliar with using Azure AD Graph API to Azure AD B2C, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Comment: Hi, @MIMUSH-MSFTE , If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as asnwer so that we can help more communities. Thanks!